# Simple Java issue actual and formal arguments lists differ in length

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a very simple script and I'm getting an error that doesn't pop up in the example provided. I have a set of code and a client to test it. I'm getting this error when I try to run the code. I get this for all three instances where I try to use "new Class" in the client.

```
ClassClient.java:5: error: constructor Class in class Class cannot be applied to given types;

     Class code = new Class("1234");
                  ^
required: String,String,String
found: String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Here is the first set of code:

```
public class Class
{
//attributes
public  String code;
private String name;
private String credit;

//constructor
public Class(String newCode, String newName, String newCredit)
{
  setCode(newCode);
  setName(newName);
  setCredit(newCredit);
}

//get|sets

public String getCode()
{
   return code;
}

public void setCode(String newCode)
{
   code = newCode;
}

public String getName()
{
   return name;
}

 public void setName(String newName)
{
   name = newName;
}

public String getCredit()
{
   return credit;
}

public void setCredit(String newCredit)
{
   credit = newCredit;
}

public String toString()
{
return ("The code for this class is: "+code + "\n" + "The name for this class is :"+name + "\n" +  "The number of credits this course has is :"+credit);
}

public boolean equals(Object o)
{
if(!(o instanceof Class))
   return false;
else
{
   Class x = (Class) o;
   Class y = (Class) o;
   Class z = (Class) o;

   return(code.equals(x.code) || name.equals(y.name) || credit.equals(z.credit));
}


}//endelse
}//end class
```

And here is the client that tests the code:

```
public class ClassClient
{
public static void main(String [] args)
  {
     Class code = new Class("1234");
     Class name = new Class("Java");
     Class credit = new Class("4");
     System.out.println("The code for this class is: "+code + "\n" + "The name for this class is :"+name + "\n" +  "The number of credits this course has is :"+credit);
  }
}
```

Comment: Check your constructor parameters number.

Comment: I would suggest to please read the compile time error which the compiler showed. Clearly mentioned there what it needs.

Answer (score 1):

`Constructor` in `class` accept `3` `String` arguments not `1`.

You can change

```
 Class code = new Class("1234"); // you are calling single argument
 Class name = new Class("Java"); // but there is no matching 
 Class credit = new Class("4"); // constructor for this
```

To

```
 Class cl = new Class("1234","Java","4");
```

Additionally to get values you should use getters.

You can change

```
System.out.println("The code for this class is: "+code + "\n" 
      + "The name for this class is :"+name + "\n" 
             +  "The number of credits this course has is :"+credit);
```

To

```
System.out.println("The code for this class is: "+cl.getCode() + "\n" 
      + "The name for this class is :"+cl.getName() + "\n" 
             +  "The number of credits this course has is "+cl.getCredit());
```

Comment: Additionally, the `println` statement should use the getter methods to get the code, name and credit of the created `Class` object.

Comment: I'm actually looking for my client to test all 3 inputs of "code" "name" and "credit" individually. Using this method doesn't it just set the strings of "1234" "java" and "4" to code instead of using all 3 predefined strings? Would I need to change how my constructor is laid out?

Comment: @MattiasBuelens yes. I added that part to answer.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much. I'm a bit inexperienced so it didn't make sense at first to me haha

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your ClassClient if you have a constructor in Class class like this.

```
  //constructor

 public Class(String somethig)
   {
     // set somethig
  }
```

but in you constructor it expecting three arguments. but you have providded only one.